Is there a better way to optimize my AWS Glue Script?
I am a novice with AWS Glue and PySpark and I am unable to resolve the problem I am facing and would require the community's help.
Task: I was tasked with creating a script on AWS Glue using PySpark to retrieve the row counts of multiple source database tables (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL etc..).
Problem: The problem I face is that the table count is huge (around 15,000) and I need to retrieve them dynamically for each database. This takes too much time (more than 2 hours) and also creates a lot of connections to the database to the point it hangs the database. I will share a sample code of what I have written to accomplish this task.
Solution: This is where I need help from the community. I need to somehow make this code work by reducing the time it takes to retrieve the results and also reduce the load on the source database by limiting connections from glue. Any resources or samples would definitely help as I;ve been stuck with this problem for 2 days.
Thanks in advance !
```python
#Reading file containing the list of database, schemas and tables

s3_input_path = "s3://path/to/csv"
# Create a DynamicFrame from the CSV file in S3

dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
connection_type="s3",
connection_options={"paths": [s3_input_path]},
format="csv",
format_options={"withHeader": True}
)

# Convert the DynamicFrame to a Spark DataFrame
df = dyf.toDF()

#Creating an empty list to collect data from each schema
results = []

schema = StructType([StructField("db_name", StringType()),
StructField("schema_name", StringType()),
StructField("table_name", StringType()),
StructField("row_count", DecimalType()),
StructField("execution_time", StringType())])

for schema_name in df.select('schema_name').distinct().collect():
    schema_name = schema_name['schema_name']

for row in df.filter(df['schema_name'] == schema_name).collect():
    table_name = row['table_name']
    db_name = row['db_name']

    query = f"""Select '{db_name}' as db_name, '{schema_name}' as schema_name, '{table_name}' as table_name, cast(count(*) AS int) as row_count, current_timestamp as execution_time from {schema_name}.{table_name}"""

    try:
     oracle_dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
     connection_type = "oracle",
     connection_options = {
     "useConnectionProperties": "true",
    "dbtable": f"{schema_name}.{table_name}",
    "sampleQuery": query,
    "connectionName": "connection",
    },
transformation_ctx = "src_oracle")

    # Convert to Spark DataFrame
    oracle_df = oracle_dyf.toDF()

    # Collect results to list
    results.extend(oracle_df.collect())

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error in {schema_name}.{table_name} : {e}")
   # Continue to the next table

# After processing all tables in the current schema, write results to a file
schema_df = spark.createDataFrame(results, schema)
schema_df = schema_df.repartition(1) # Ensure single output file
file_path = "s3://path/to/target"

if schema_df.count() > 0:
    schema_df.write.mode('append').csv(file_path)

# Clear results for the next schema
    results.clear()```

What I have done so far is that I have a file stored in s3 which contains the schema names and table names. I read this file and loop through the schema names and table names and generate a dynamic script to send to the source to retrieve the counts. The sources lie in a subnet and I have to use the dynamicframe reader api so I can retrieve the connections from Glue and also apply the subnet for the current job.

Iterate on database X schema level, and make a single statement to count all tables from the current database X schema values.
The query will look similar to the one returned by this :
 Select count(*) , 'table1'  from   table1  Union ALL
 Select count(*) , 'table2'  from   table2  Union ALL ....


Hi, thank you. This worked much faster

You're welcome! Does this mean I'll get a big thumbs up from you? Just kidding... I'm just happy I could help!
